# Can connect over RDP, but can not ping remote machine

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, remote-connection

There is a virtual machine with IP (let's say) 192.168.1.150. I can connect to it from our local network over RDP, but when I try to ping it all the packages are lost.

Also tried `Start->Run: \\192.168.1.150\C$` and it leads to an error dialog window:

> Windows cannot access \\192.168.1.150\C$
>
> Error code: 0x800070035
>
> The network path was not found.

Actually I need to connect to this machine in HP LoadRunner Controller, but it does not because of the problem described above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is obviously a firewall problem.

Check the firewall on your virtual machine *guest* and make sure it allows ping and SMB shares.

Check the firewall of your virtual machine *host* and make sure it allows everything you need. Check also that the host does the routing well. Do you use a host-based NAT with port forwarding? Then you need to add forwarding rules for SMB.

Check the middleboxes of your network and make sure they do not block SMB. Some routers do block it as default.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to enable the ping option follow the below steps:

To enable go to windows firewall > "Allow app or feature through windows firewall" > check the box "File and Printer" to enable.
Now try to ping it should work...